# this give me error msg if empty all checkboxes but run insert query and data inserted

Tags: php, checkbox

```
function checkbox() {
    // body...

    var a = document.getElementsByName('proinf[]');
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i].checked == true) {
            document.getElementById("error_checkbox").innerHTML = "";
            return true;
        }else {
            document.getElementById("error_checkbox").innerHTML = "* Please Checked Atleast 1 Professional Skill";
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<input id="sbmtbtn" type="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"    onclick="return checkbox()" name="Submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: Please check community rules on how to ask questions. I see your new but you can't just post code and ask a vague question in the title, you need to clearly state what your problem is, what you have done so far, and what result your expecting then we can help.

Comment: Your function is not returning `false` anywhere, but it needs to do that, if you want to prevent the default form submit action this way.

Comment: if i add return false; in else.....it show me error but when i checked some boxes and click submit it show me error msg and not inserted ?

Comment: There isn't any php in this php question.  What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this----

function checkbox() {
    // body...
    var ischecked=false;
    var a = document.getElementsByName('proinf[]');
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i].checked == true) {
            ischecked=true;
        }
    }   
    if(ischecked===true){
        document.getElementById("error_checkbox").innerHTML = "";
        return true;
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("error_checkbox").innerHTML = "* Please Checked Atleast 1 Professional Skill";
        return false;
    }
}
```